# The Laravel project stucks an error in php artisan

Tags: php, laravel

```
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\\Users\\domini...', 1349)
#1 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(576): include('C:\\Users\\domini...')
#2 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}('C:\\Users\\domini...')
#3 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
#5 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
#6 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#7 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#8 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main} in C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 11

In Collection.php line 11:

  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExi
  sts($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWill
  Change] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Lar
  avel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection
  .php:1349
  Stack trace:
  #0 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleEr
  ror(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\\Users\\domini...', 1349)
  #1 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\comp
  oser\ClassLoader.php(576): include('C:\\Users\\domini...')
  #2 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\comp
  oser\ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}('C:\\Users\\domini...')
  #3 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp..
  .')
  #4 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
  #5 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()
  #6 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest
  ()
  #7 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('ali
  ases')
  #8 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->a
  liases()
  #9 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lara
  vel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->boot
  strap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
  #10 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lar
  avel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(
  Array)
  #11 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\vendor\lar
  avel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
  #12 C:\Users\dominicsham\Downloads\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\Ecommerce-Laravel-Bootstrap-master\artisan(35
  ): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\C
  omponent\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
  #13 {main}
```

I am trying to clone a project and whenever I run `php artisan` with any commands it stucks with the above error. Even I checked the version is the correct PHP version and I run `composer install` the error could not be fixed properly. May I ask how to fix the solution in order to have the application run successfully?

Comment: You said you checked the PHP version. What is the PHP version you are using? The PHP version of the cloned project?

Comment: Did a quick google search and most of the answers provided was to upgrade or downgrade PHP version to match with the required PHP version of the project.

Comment: I think the version is not a problem instead I do not understand what the error message means above?

Comment: Can you share your composer.json and php version of the system?

Comment: The error say *incompatible version*. You can downgrade your php version, upgraded your laravel or check [these](https://bytexd.com/fix-laravel-return-type-of-illuminatesupportcollectionoffsetexistskey/) steps.

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you that a class method in an inherited class has an incompatible return type with the method in its parent class. This causes errors in PHP8.1+.

ArrayAccess is a built-in PHP interface (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) used widely in the Laravel framework. The ArrayAccess::offsetExists() method provides a return type of 'bool' as of PHP8.1. If a method somewhere in the Laravel code has the effect of extending the ArrayAccess::offsetExists() method (or implementing the interface, which is what is happening here), but fails to declare a return type or returns something other than a boolean, the error will be triggered.

I note that Laravel 10 does not even have the mentioned Illuminate\Support\Collection class any more, so the version of the Laravel framework you are using must be older. I am sure the Laravel framework version used by your code is not compatible with the version of PHP you are running (8.1+).

I know you said 'I think the version is not a problem', but I am sure it *is* the problem. Type errors are almost inevitable if an older version of Laravel is run with a newer version of PHP where type declarations are implemented widely.

Here's the problem method as it existed in Laravel 7 ([github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php):1344) :

```
/**
* Determine if an item exists at an offset.
*
* @param  mixed  $key
* @return bool
*/
public function offsetExists($key)
{
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->items);
}
```

That was fine for PHP up to 8.1, but it will break with PHP 8.1+. It would need to read:

```
public function offsetExists($key): void 
{
     return array_key_exists($key, $this->items);
}
```

The fix will be to  upgrade the Laravel framework (likely not possible if you are cloning somebody else's code) or downgrading PHP to 8.0.

It's somewhat noteworthy that the Laravel Framework in version 7 stated '^PHP8.0' as a dependency, which implied compatibility with versions of PHP that weren't and still aren't yet released. But I guess PHP doesn't really use  proper semantic versioning, so this is what happens when major non-backwards compatible changes are introduced in minor versions.

Comment: Which file should I modify with the above code? I could not find any files including those

Comment: you can't technically modify them since they are inside vendor folder. If you do it may do something unexpected in your system. Just tell us the PHP version in your system and the required PHP version in the composer

Comment: @Dom we told you a million times that you have to downgrade your PHP version, you are not sharing what PHP version you have installed, please, DOWNGRADE your PHP version to something older than 8.2, like 8.1 or 8.0 and see if it works...

Comment: As @Mr.Kenneth mentioned, making any code changes to try to fix the problem will only get you into more problems. Your Laravel install and PHP version are incompatible, and trying to hack it into working makes no sense. Downgrading PHP and/or running multiple versions of PHP on your development server is relatively trivial. That's the way to go.